# Compare bits in assembly 

Tags: assembly, 8051, microprocessors

How can I compare two bits if they are equal or not in 8051? I need to jump if two bits are equal.
I have a value in a register and I am searching if this value is equal another constant value. Example: I have "EDh" value and I have another value in R0 register.

Comment: Two bits within the same register?  Or the same bit position in each of two registers?

Comment: I have a value in a register and I am searching if this value is equal another constant value. Example: I have "EDh" value and I have another value in R0 register.

Comment: Which bit should be compared?

Comment: All of them should compare together.

Comment: Then your question (and title) are misleading!  They say that you only want to compare *two* bits.  Perhaps you should edit your question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compare a register and an immediate (a constant), and then conditionally jump, you can use the [`CJNE`](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/is51/is51_cjne.htm) instruction.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a long time since I worked with the 8051. But I seem to remember that the [CJNE](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/comp/8051/set8051.html#51cjne) instruction was quite useful.